# Website showing cheap flight offers for Germany

Tags: air-travel, budget, online-resources, germany, tips-and-tricks

I am looking for some source (fb, twitter, website etc) where is posted from time to time cheap offers of flights (mostly interested from Germany). For example there is a cool fb page called "mleczne podróze" for Poland.

Comment: The questions seems to be broad, since there are many websites in different languages in many countries

Comment: I am not very familiar with detailed rules, but since Im asking in English one language is obvious, Im asking for Germany-I speak German. Those two languages are preferable, and about country I think Im specific, I want it for Germany... Am I violating some rules?

Comment: I have voted to leave open this question. It is narrowed down to a specific geographic region for which (in any language) there exist at most some 20 relevant blogs etc. It is useful for someone planning budget travels and indeed I'm using some of these sites on a daily basis. I disagree with the close votes. Please suggest an edit if you disagree. Disclaimer: I have posted the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good collection of sites, however be aware that these are mostly in German, so Google translate might be useful. Here are some examples but there's more. At least travel-dealz is somewhat transparent about their sources so check where they get their inspiration from and follow these as well. Also they typically publish vacation/hotel deals as well that you might be less interested in. At least Urlaubspiraten has a good filter though (I'm already linking to flight only deals below).

- [Travel Dealz](http://travel-dealz.de/)
- [Exbir](http://www.exbir.de/)
- [Urlaubspiraten](http://www.urlaubspiraten.de/fluge)

They take much of their inspiration from forums such as [Vielfliegertreff](http://www.vielfliegertreff.de/) (in German, the international equivalent is [Flyertalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/)) where cheap/error fares are typically discussed first (if you want to become active be aware the tone is somewhat rough).

There's also a few similar websites with an European focus that might be as useful to follow. My favorites are

- [Fly4free](http://www.fly4free.com/)
- [Secretflying](http://www.secretflying.com/euro-deals/)

If you are looking for resources on twitter, this luxury travel blog has a [very decent list of twitter accounts to follow.](http://youhavebeenupgraded.boardingarea.com/2014/07/twitter/) (The guy is Austrian, the website in German and his travels / the list international, so pick what you find useful).

Needless to say, sometimes there's many good deals and sometimes just nothing, you have to be patient and ready to book when time comes around. Good luck!